# Creating entries based on user input

Tags: php, post

I have a input form where the person filling it out can select how many hires they are creating and there is an entry for each new hire.  The problem that I am having is that I try to run a loop after this is submitted, but when I test it out the mots I can create is 3 ( the person creating the form will be able to select from 1-10).

I have the following code:

```
function dataloop ($entry_id, $form_id) {

if ($form_id==37) {
            //$barge=$_POST['item_meta'][734];



    $args=array();
    $args['1']=$_POST['item_meta'][694];   //submitter_login field
    $args['2']=$_POST['item_meta'][690];  //submitter_first_name
    $args['3']=$_POST['item_meta'][691];  // submitter_last_name
    $args['4']=$_POST['item_meta'][734];  //Dropdown for new hires



 //store the array into a variable

    $ulog=$args['1'];                      
    $ufname=$args['2'];                   
    $ulname=$args['3'];                  
    $edrop=$args['4'];                  


             global $frm_entry, $user_ID;


             for ($i=1; $i <=$edrop; $i++) {



    $frm_entry->create(array(
        'form_id'=>'37',
        'item_key'=>'entry',
        'frm_user_id'=> $user_ID,
         'item_meta'=>array(
        694 => $ulog,       
        690 => $ufname,
            691 => $ulname    

           ),));}  }}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `$edrop` variable is a `string`, and thus your `for loop` loops through the number of chars in the string (3).

You should set `$edrop` like so;

```
 $edrop = intval($args['4']);
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, I have tried this and have also changed it to for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) and it still returns with just 3.

Comment: Is it possible that the call to $frm_entry->create won't create duplicate entries since the form ID does not change or something? 

Are you able to echo out in that loop to confirm its going 10 times?

Comment: Well, I don't know about that, because I was definitely able to create an infinite loop while working on this and it added correctly, lol.  so, I think the class is able to create multiple entries.

Comment: Are you able to echo out in that loop to confirm its going 10 times?

Comment: I tried doing an <?php echo $dataloop ?> after it is submitted and nothing shows up? I am really appreciative of your help, kind of new to php.

Comment: I assume this is a for submit/ajax request, do you return anything back to the client?

Comment: After creating entry the plugin then re-directs the customer to a web page where it creates a display with the information that they submitted.